# Issue in hide and show of n level Menu Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an N level menu structure where I have to hide the child menus in all levels at first and show them on hover of the parent menu..I had been trying this I got to hide all the children and show them on click but the issue is when I click on other parent the menu which is previuosly opened has to be closed and its child should be in hidden state if I go click that menu again and I want some easing and animation effects while opening and closing the menu it should work as a toggle.

This is what I have been trying to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("li").children('ul').hide();
$("li a").click(function(){
$(this).next('ul').toggle();            
$(this).parent().siblings('li').children('ul').hide();
```

here is [the](http://jsfiddle.net/kKsXz/) js fiddle of what i am trying to do

Comment: Why using some jquery to display some submenu ? You could do it in pure CSS with a better accessibility, like those for example http://cssmenumaker.com/css-vertical-menus

Comment: What you describe seems to be working already. Are you mostly interested in the animation part?

Comment: i should not use any classes and or any attributes on the menu only the top level ul has the class remaining every thing should be done in jquery

Comment: @Matt yes animation and there is an issue there if i open a menu open all the sub levels of it and if i go to other parent the childs and all levels of that should be closed if i visit that menu again

Comment: @Matt and i need the easing and animation part to